# Socket IO Error while handshaking Caused by java.net.SocketTimeoutException

Tags: java, android, socket.io

Hi I am new with this  
I have a client on my android phone and I want to connect to a SocketIO server on the Raspberry Pi. 
I have take this client example https://github.com/fatshotty/socket.io-java-client/blob/master/examples/basic/BasicExample2.java 
I change the ip address and the port. When I run it i get this problem

 
03-21 11:37:09.469  19973-20232/com.example.app I/System.out﹕ an Error occured 
03-21 11:37:09.469  19973-20232/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ io.socket.SocketIOException: Error while handshaking
03-21 11:37:09.470  19973-20232/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at io.socket.IOConnection.handshake(IOConnection.java:322)
03-21 11:37:09.470  19973-20232/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at io.socket.IOConnection.access$600(IOConnection.java:39)
03-21 11:37:09.470  19973-20232/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at io.socket.IOConnection$ConnectThread.run(IOConnection.java:199)
03-21 11:37:09.470  19973-20232/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
03-21 11:37:09.471  19973-20232/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:495)
03-21 11:37:09.471  19973-20232/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
03-21 11:37:09.471  19973-20232/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
03-21 11:37:09.471  19973-20232/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:163)
03-21 11:37:09.471  19973-20232/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:142)
03-21 11:37:09.472  19973-20232/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:227)
03-21 11:37:09.472  19973-20232/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:201)
03-21 11:37:09.472  19973-20232/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponseHeaders(HttpEngine.java:573)
03-21 11:37:09.472  19973-20232/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:821)
03-21 11:37:09.472  19973-20232/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:293)
03-21 11:37:09.472  19973-20232/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:185)
03-21 11:37:09.473  19973-20232/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ at io.socket.IOConnection.handshake(IOConnection.java:313)
03-21 11:37:09.473  19973-20232/com.example.app W/System.err﹕ ... 2 more

Some one know what I can do ?

Comment: Increase your timeout. It's too short.

Comment: I increase it but still got the error only later